# iOS Localization file with Ukraine language is not working

Tags: ios, swift, localization

I have problem with localization app. So I will have 3 languages:

1. English
2. Russian
3. Ukrainian

And I create localization files:

[image]

And I translate this file to `Ukrainian`:

```
    /* Class = "UIButton"; normalTitle = "Start"; ObjectID = "nAo-pY-eyH"; */
"nAo-pY-eyH.normalTitle" = "Старт";

/* Class = "UILabel"; text = "year"; ObjectID = "qiX-mI-YVI"; */
"qiX-mI-YVI.text" = "Рік";

/* Class = "UIButton"; normalTitle = "START TESTING"; ObjectID = "rHr-P9-7MM"; */
"rHr-P9-7MM.normalTitle" = "ПОЧАТИ ТЕСТУВАННЯ";

/* Class = "UILabel"; text = "Detail"; ObjectID = "tNb-3z-yWj"; */
"tNb-3z-yWj.text" = "Деталі";

/* Class = "UITextField"; placeholder = "E-mail"; ObjectID = "tbQ-Wo-JMl"; */
"tbQ-Wo-JMl.placeholder" = "E-mail";

/* Class = "UIButton"; normalTitle = "Sign In"; ObjectID = "v54-H1-c5F"; */
"v54-H1-c5F.normalTitle" = "Вхід";
```

At device setup I chose region `Ukraine`, and language `Ukrainian`.

This I print in console:

[image]

Code:

```
let langCode = Locale.current.languageCode
    let regionCode = Locale.current.regionCode
    let language = "\(langCode!)-\(regionCode!)"
    print(language)
    let preferredLanguage = Locale.preferredLanguages[0] as String
    print (preferredLanguage)
```

But I still not get result, and my app is not translate, for `Russian` lang is working.

I really tried to find a solution.

Comment: Are you sure your localised `uk-UA` files are in a valid format? Are strings from your `localizable.strings` file translated OK? Or is the problem just with your storyboard strings file?

Comment: @ Ashley Mills It's problem only with storyboard strings file

Comment: OK, I just want to clarify - you have `localizable.strings` files and text in them is being translated correctly?

Comment: @Ashley Mills yes it's translate correctly

Comment: did you find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

From your comments (`localizable.strings` is translated correctly), we can see that the problem is isn't generally translating to `uk-UA`, but with your storyboard strings file.

It's very easy to mess these files up, so you need to check that it is exactly the correct format. Some times the compiler will help, other times it doesn't.

I've found the easiest way to debug this is to remove all but the first translation from the file, check that is working, and then gradually re-add more translations back until you find the problem.

For example, so start with just

```
"nAo-pY-eyH.normalTitle" = "Старт";
```

check that the button is translated correctly, and go on from there.